# Simulink Masks: Can I get the variables to persist in memory?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a parameter in my simulink mask: `refName`. In the Mask Initialization tab, I first initialize it as a 1 x 300 vector of type `double`. I have to do this because this vector is further propagated to a C++ S-Function, where the arrays cannot (easily) be of variable sizes.

After this, in the same initialization tab, it is assigned a value based on the user's input of another parameter `refType`. So, for example, if refType is 'R32', refName might be [1 2 3] (not all 300 cells are used), if refType is R410A, refName might be [4 5 6] and so on.

The problem I am having is in trying to send this variable to the workspace (as a variable `refNameU`) *before* simulation starts. I tried setting `refNameU = get_param(gcb,'refName')` in the CloseFcn, InitFcn *and* LoadFcn block callbacks, but for some reason, the value in the workspace is always zero regardless of which callback it gets called from. And not a vector of size 300 with all zeros, but just zero.

For reference, I have the 'Evaluate', 'Enable Parameter' and 'Tunable' options for the refName parameter all checked. Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and how I can solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you say it's not easy to handle different array sizes with S-Functions? You should be able to get all the info you need using `mxGetNumberOfDimensions`, `mxGetM`, `mxGetN` etc.

Comment: @Praetorian You're probably right. However, my experience level with Simulink isn't extensive, so I just used the most straightforward method I knew. Basically, I had some Matlab code that I converted to a C++ S-Function first by using the Matlab Coder and then using the Legacy Code compilation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [assignin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) within the `CloseFcn` callback to assign the variable in the base workspace.

```
assignin('base', 'refNameU', refName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it still seems to assign it a value of 0. Also, I learnt that `CloseFcn` callbacks only work if the function is being closed programmatically, not interactively through the mask GUI.

Comment: @UnaEngineer Is `refNameU` already defined in the base workspace with initial value of 0, or did adding the `assignin` create it? I don't have Simulink handy to try it out myself, so could you add a `disp` statement right before the `assignin` to display the value of `refName`? Also, adding `evalin('base', 'disp(refNameU)');` right after the `assignin` might be useful in tracing whether the variable is being overwritten sometime after you assign it a value. Looks like you are right about `CloseFcn`. Depending on when the variable needs to be available, the `StartFcn` callback might work.

Comment: It worked! For anyone reading in the future, the trick is to do this in the Initialization tab of the mask, and not in the callback. To clarify, your answer already worked, even without the comment. Thanks again!